# App is crashing on startup in Apple App review, but I cannot replicate it

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Can anyone help me with this crash? It crashes on start up according to the App Review. It was written in C# using Xamarin iOS. I've tested the app in debug, release, and TestFlight on both iPad and iPhone and haven't been able to replicate the crash.

Here's part of the crashlog, I couldn't fit the whole thing in the question. If you need anymore information let me know.

```
Incident Identifier: 432AD166-AABB-4FC4-AF07-4EBDFEE80E9D
CrashReporter Key:   7f13e1dee0a0434b3c240288b1caae098e3628f0
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             App.iOS [22414]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/16369005-2E1C-4457-A763-5E8AAECBAE73/App.iOS.app/App.iOS
Identifier:          com.Name.App
Version:             1.5.2 (1.5.2)
AppStoreTools:       14C17
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.Name.App [7168]

Date/Time:           2023-03-21 14:26:38.9981 -0700
Launch Time:         2023-03-21 14:26:33.2442 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.3.1 (20D67)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  22

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0 name:  tid_103 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72da8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85a1c mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85c5c mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc732ec mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea82ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea83d08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea88eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   GraphicsServices                       0x1d83d0368 GSEventRunModal + 164
8   UIKitCore                              0x1a0f7e668 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
9   UIKitCore                              0x1a0f7e2cc UIApplicationMain + 340
10  App.iOS                        0x10871a09c xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 24
11  App.iOS                        0x103951ccc wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_xamarin_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr_intptr_ + 380
12  App.iOS                        0x1039db88c Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 11761804 (UIApplication.cs:58)
13  App.iOS                        0x1085932d0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 91157200 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
14  App.iOS                        0x10864cf1c mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 91918108 (object.c:3220)
15  App.iOS                        0x108653224 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 91943460 (object.c:5288)
16  App.iOS                        0x1085715e0 mono_jit_exec + 91018720 (driver.c:1328)
17  App.iOS                        0x10872e460 xamarin_main + 92841056 (monotouch-main.m:0)
18  App.iOS                        0x1034ba98c main + 6384012 (main.m:294)
19  dyld                                   0x1bd374960 start + 2528

Thread 1 name:   Dispatch queue: com.google.firebase.firestore.rpc
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc76494 poll + 8
1   grpc                                   0x109dbfadc pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, long long) + 1172
2   grpc                                   0x109dc1974 pollset_work(grpc_pollset*, grpc_pollset_worker**, long long) + 72
3   grpc                                   0x109db3ccc cq_next(grpc_completion_queue*, gpr_timespec, void*) + 520
4   grpcpp                                 0x10a1171c0 grpc_impl::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void**, bool*, gpr_timespec) + 60
5   App.iOS                        0x1032f8984 firebase::firestore::remote::Datastore::PollGrpcQueue() + 4540804 (datastore.cc:137)
6   App.iOS                        0x1033e216c firebase::firestore::util::Task::ExecuteAndRelease() + 5497196 (task.cc:107)
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a6028f88 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a6030640 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a603118c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a603be10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b98 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  SGen worker
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   App.iOS                        0x1086f0144 thread_func + 92586308 (sgen-thread-pool.c:196)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72da8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85a1c mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85c5c mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc732ec mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea82ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea83d08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea88eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   CFNetwork                              0x19fdf3ff0 0x19fb9c000 + 2457584
8   Foundation                             0x198e49518 __NSThread__start__ + 716
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:  Finalizer
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72d24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   App.iOS                        0x1085ef81c finalizer_thread + 91535388 (gc.c:965)
2   App.iOS                        0x10869aa74 start_wrapper_internal + 92236404 (threads.c:1289)
3   App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72da8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85a1c mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85c5c mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc732ec mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea82ac4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea83d08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19ea88eb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x198e30054 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x198e2ff3c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x1a10b36a4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 436
10  Foundation                             0x198e49518 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 name:  com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72da8 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85a1c mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc85c5c mach_msg_overwrite + 388
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc732ec mach_msg + 24
4   App.iOS                        0x103455ca0 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 5971104 (FIRCLSMachException.c:170)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13 name:  Timer-Scheduler
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   App.iOS                        0x1086ff6c0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 92649152 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   App.iOS                        0x1086a619c mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle + 92283292 (w32handle.c:767)
4   App.iOS                        0x1086a6074 mono_w32handle_wait_one + 92282996 (w32handle.c:895)
5   App.iOS                        0x1086a6298 mono_w32handle_wait_multiple + 92283544 (w32handle.c:1002)
6   App.iOS                        0x108694fa0 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal + 92213152 (threads.c:2314)
7   App.iOS                        0x108610f40 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_raw + 91672384 (icall-def.h:1100)
8   App.iOS                        0x1034cd738 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_intptr__int_bool_int + 120
9   App.iOS                        0x1036fd4ec mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool + 8754412 (WaitHandle.cs:0)
10  App.iOS                        0x1036f5218 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 8720920 (executioncontext.cs:911)
11  App.iOS                        0x1085932d0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 91157200 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
12  App.iOS                        0x10864cf1c mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 91918108 (object.c:3220)
13  App.iOS                        0x1086528b8 mono_runtime_delegate_try_invoke + 91941048 (object.c:4441)
14  App.iOS                        0x10869ab6c start_wrapper_internal + 92236652 (threads.c:1258)
15  App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 14 name:  tid_a403
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   App.iOS                        0x1086ff6c0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 92649152 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   App.iOS                        0x108708428 mono_thread_info_sleep + 92685352 (mono-threads.c:1673)
4   App.iOS                        0x10868ec20 monitor_thread + 92187680 (threadpool-worker-default.c:728)
5   App.iOS                        0x10869aa74 start_wrapper_internal + 92236404 (threads.c:1289)
6   App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 15 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72d3c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   App.iOS                        0x10868f4d8 worker_thread + 92189912 (threadpool-worker-default.c:490)
2   App.iOS                        0x10869aa74 start_wrapper_internal + 92236404 (threads.c:1289)
3   App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 16 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   App.iOS                        0x1086ff6e8 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 92649192 (mono-os-mutex.c:32)
3   App.iOS                        0x1086a619c mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle + 92283292 (w32handle.c:767)
4   App.iOS                        0x1086a6074 mono_w32handle_wait_one + 92282996 (w32handle.c:895)
5   App.iOS                        0x10863fac0 ves_icall_System_Threading_Monitor_Monitor_wait + 91863744 (monitor.c:1499)
6   App.iOS                        0x10860f524 ves_icall_System_Threading_Monitor_Monitor_wait_raw + 91665700 (icall-def.h:999)
7   App.iOS                        0x1034cbdf8 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_Monitor_Monitor_wait_object_int + 104
8   App.iOS                        0x1036f6e18 mscorlib_System_Threading_Monitor_ObjWait_bool_int_object + 8728088 (Monitor.cs:0)
9   App.iOS                        0x103acf630 System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1_T_REF_TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation_T_REF__int_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_CancellationTokenSource + 12760624 (BlockingCollection.cs:701)
10  App.iOS                        0x103c55988 System_System_Collections_Concurrent_BlockingCollection_1_T_REF_TryTake_T_REF__int_System_Threading_CancellationToken + 14358920 (BlockingCollection.cs:0)
11  App.iOS                        0x1065fd0a0 MQTTnet_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_Start_MQTTnet_Server_MqttClientSessionsManager__TryProcessNextQueuedApplicationMessageAsyncd__24_MQTTnet_Server_MqttClientSessionsManager__TryProcessNextQueuedApplicationMessageAsyncd__24_ + 58036384 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:320)
12  App.iOS                        0x1065fd040 MQTTnet_System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncTaskMethodBuilder_Start_MQTTnet_Server_MqttClientSessionsManager__TryProcessQueuedApplicationMessagesAsyncd__23_MQTTnet_Server_MqttClientSessionsManager__TryProcessQueuedApplicationMessagesAsyncd__23_ + 58036288 (AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:320)
13  App.iOS                        0x1036f5218 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 8720920 (executioncontext.cs:911)
14  App.iOS                        0x103709074 mscorlib_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ExecuteEntry_bool + 8802420 (Task.cs:0)
15  App.iOS                        0x103a24588 Xamarin_iOS_ObjCRuntime_Runtime_ThreadPoolDispatcher_System_Func_1_bool + 12060040 (Runtime.cs:0)
16  App.iOS                        0x1085932d0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 91157200 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
17  App.iOS                        0x10864e808 mono_runtime_try_invoke + 91924488 (object.c:3161)
18  App.iOS                        0x108691a6c worker_callback + 92199532 (threadpool.c:386)
19  App.iOS                        0x10868f2e0 worker_thread + 92189408 (threadpool-worker-default.c:502)
20  App.iOS                        0x10869aa74 start_wrapper_internal + 92236404 (threads.c:1289)
21  App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314b90 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   grpc                                   0x109e2b788 gpr_cv_wait + 124
3   grpc                                   0x109dc3484 grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) + 184
4   grpc                                   0x109e35498 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   grpc                                   0x109e2b788 gpr_cv_wait + 124
3   grpc                                   0x109dc3484 grpc_core::Executor::ThreadMain(void*) + 184
4   grpc                                   0x109e35498 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   grpc                                   0x109e2b778 gpr_cv_wait + 108
3   grpc                                   0x109e388ec timer_thread(void*) + 532
4   grpc                                   0x109e35498 grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadInternalsPosix::ThreadInternalsPosix(char const*, void (*)(void*), void*, bool*, grpc_core::Thread::Options const&)::'lambda'(void*)::__invoke(void*) + 140
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 21 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc72d3c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   App.iOS                        0x10868f4d8 worker_thread + 92189912 (threadpool-worker-default.c:490)
2   App.iOS                        0x10869aa74 start_wrapper_internal + 92236404 (threads.c:1289)
3   App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 22 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 22 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc79674 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31b1ac pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a60e43e4 __abort + 128
3   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1a608cc98 abort + 192
4   App.iOS                        0x108725b04 xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type + 92805892 (runtime.m:1189)
5   App.iOS                        0x1085ec414 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 91522068 (exception.c:1299)
6   App.iOS                        0x10869a45c mono_thread_internal_unhandled_exception + 92234844 (threads.c:6010)
7   App.iOS                        0x108691ad4 worker_callback + 92199636 (threadpool.c:0)
8   App.iOS                        0x10868f2e0 worker_thread + 92189408 (threadpool-worker-default.c:502)
9   App.iOS                        0x10869aa74 start_wrapper_internal + 92236404 (threads.c:1289)
10  App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 23 name:  tid_3c0b
Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1dbc7367c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec31c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232
2   App.iOS                        0x1086ff6c0 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 92649152 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   App.iOS                        0x108708428 mono_thread_info_sleep + 92685352 (mono-threads.c:1673)
4   App.iOS                        0x108693c34 ves_icall_System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_internal + 92208180 (threads.c:1845)
5   App.iOS                        0x108610520 ves_icall_System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_internal_raw + 91669792 (icall-def.h:1040)
6   App.iOS                        0x1034cc070 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_Thread_SleepInternal_int + 96
7   App.iOS                        0x1036f7b8c mscorlib_System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_System_TimeSpan + 8731532 (thread.cs:812)
8   App.iOS                        0x1065a4e74 MQTTnet_MQTTnet_Server_MqttServerKeepAliveMonitor__c__DisplayClass4_0__Startb__0_object + 20
9   App.iOS                        0x1036f5218 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 8720920 (executioncontext.cs:911)
10  App.iOS                        0x103709074 mscorlib_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ExecuteEntry_bool + 8802420 (Task.cs:0)
11  App.iOS                        0x1036f5218 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 8720920 (executioncontext.cs:911)
12  App.iOS                        0x1085932d0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 91157200 (mini-runtime.c:3191)
13  App.iOS                        0x10864cf1c mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 91918108 (object.c:3220)
14  App.iOS                        0x1086528b8 mono_runtime_delegate_try_invoke + 91941048 (object.c:4441)
15  App.iOS                        0x10869ab6c start_wrapper_internal + 92236652 (threads.c:1258)
16  App.iOS                        0x10869a8f8 start_wrapper + 92236024 (threads.c:1310)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec3156cc _pthread_start + 148
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1ec314ba4 thread_start + 8

Thread 22 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000001200   x7: 0xffffffff00000c00
    x8: 0x2dc423abece235b1   x9: 0x2dc423aa82b745b1  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x000000011af47800  x13: 0x000000010c3aaf13  x14: 0x00000000000000e0  x15: 0x0000000080000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016e557000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000009103  x21: 0x000000016e5570e0  x22: 0x0000000000000082  x23: 0x0000000281a63d80
   x24: 0x0000000124a6c400  x25: 0x000000010c3ac778  x26: 0x0000000108f36000  x27: 0x0000000108f364e0
   x28: 0x0000000108f36538   fp: 0x000000016e556bd0   lr: 0x00000001ec31b1ac
    sp: 0x000000016e556bb0   pc: 0x00000001dbc79674 cpsr: 0x40000000
   far: 0x0000000119779008  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1dbc72000 -        0x1dbca9feb libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <c76e6bed463530c68f19fb829bbe1ae1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x19ea08000 -        0x19ededfff CoreFoundation arm64e  <42ccfc7bff323d258f01ccb2ad843a8b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1d83cf000 -        0x1d83d7fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <85419099269b336d86b40d52d0ff6923> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1a0bdd000 -        0x1a23d0fff UIKitCore arm64e  <cf21ad9cefbf3961a7c054bd30cefea9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x102ea4000 -        0x1089cffff App.iOS arm64  <4d7629105d1b35a990677a0d08acf170> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/16369005-2E1C-4457-A763-5E8AAECBAE73/App.iOS.app/App.iOS
       0x1bd35f000 -        0x1bd3e2093 dyld arm64e  <4b042f280d1430eca1de3dbb10866ad7> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x109d74000 -        0x109ebbfff grpc arm64  <fecc71db1ff036b1bf861008c6743cdf> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/16369005-2E1C-4457-A763-5E8AAECBAE73/App.iOS.app/Frameworks/grpc.framework/grpc
       0x10a10c000 -        0x10a147fff grpcpp arm64  <92766c3033453065a14896c21ec7080c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/16369005-2E1C-4457-A763-5E8AAECBAE73/App.iOS.app/Frameworks/grpcpp.framework/grpcpp
       0x1a6025000 -        0x1a606bfff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <ded4d0a5142032ae83a6c31d938a1c9a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1ec314000 -        0x1ec31ffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <45ac734e66493ee2a0963fd66441ab78> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x19fb9c000 -        0x19ff65fff CFNetwork arm64e  <7f3313c9143533338c82dc961429d0b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
       0x198dee000 -        0x199737fff Foundation arm64e  <e5f615c7cc5e3656860041c767812a35> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1a606c000 -        0x1a60ebff7 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <3cd8c9e025fd3b29850774cdffe7f16c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib

EOF
```

Comment: Per the stack trace of thread 22 you have some unhandled (managed) exception into the thread pool thread. You can try `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event to catch and log the problem details (managed stack, etc). It shuld work for desktop environment, but I'm unsure that this will work on phisical device due to AOT/linker/etc.

Comment: Have you tried starting your app with no network connection? You should also try the "100% packet loss" network link conditioner under the developer menu in your iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not sure if this will help you,

Once I had the same issue and that was 'coz -
I created the `archive` while selecting my `iOS Device`. You need to choose `Any iOS Device(arm64)`.